# declarar un objeto con el nombre de una variable java

Tags: java

Hola tengo el siguiente codigo

```
while (x <= 5){
            System.out.println("introduce tu nombre");
            String nombre = input.next();
            System.out.println("Introduce tu edad ");
            int edad = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("introduce tu altura");
            float altura = input.nextFloat();
            System.out.println("introduce tu nota de expediente");
            int notaExpediente = input.nextInt();
            persona_antonio_martin_sosa antonio1 = new persona_antonio_martin_sosa(nombre,edad,altura,notaExpediente);
            System.out.println(antonio1.toString());
            x = x + 1;
        }
```

Lo que me gustaria hacer seria que a la hora de declarar el objeto se cree utilizando el nombre de una variable para asi poder crear 5 objetos distintos en el bucle no se si me explico

```
Entrada: nombre del objeto
persona_antonio_martin_sosa VARIABLE CON EL NOMBRE DEL OBJETO = new persona_antonio_martin_sosa(nombre,edad,altura,notaExpediente);
```

MUCHAS GRACIAS

Comment: ¿Esto es un ejercicio? Pregunto porque hay formas más sencillas de hacer esto, por ejemplo, creando las instancias y metiéndolas en una colección.

Comment: Puedes decirme como?

Comment: Supongamos que tu clase se llama `Persona`, fuera del `while` creas un objeto del tipo: `ArrayList<Persona> lstPeople= new ArrayList<Persona>();` y luego, dentro del `while` lo vas llenando: `lstPeople.add(new Persona(nombre,edad,altura,notaExpediente));` Al final, `lstPeople` tendrá todas las instancias de `Persona` que hayas creado dentro del `while`.  Debes entender que no es factible tener una clase como tal por cada nombre de persona, las clases son como un molde para construir instancias de `Persona`. No tiene sentido una clase llamada `persona_antonio_martin_sosa`.

Comment: Vale muchas gracias

Comment: ahora hago la respuesta y ves que tal lo hice

Comment: @A. Cedano ya he creado la respuesta mirala porfavor a ver que te parece

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El codigo finalmente quedo asi:

```
 while (x < 5){//bucle para crear 5 objetos
        System.out.println("introduce tu nombre");
        String nombre = input.next();
        System.out.println("Introduce tu edad ");
        int edad = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("introduce tu altura");
        float altura = input.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("introduce tu nota de expediente");
        int notaExpediente = input.nextInt();
        arrayObjetos[x] = new persona_antonio_martin_sosa(nombre,edad,altura,notaExpediente);
        x = x + 1;
    }
```

Aqui cada persona se guarda en una array de objetos para asi tener 5 personas en una sola lista y luego poder trabajar con ellos.
Gracias a @A.Cedano por la idea de meter los objetos en una array

Comment: Perfecto. Lo importante es que lo pruebes y veas si te funciona y hace lo que necesitas. Aunque tener una clase llamada `persona_antonio_martin_sosa` resulta muy extraño.

Comment: JAJAJAJA ya lo se pero es por que nos pedia hacerlo con nuestro nombre

Comment: Ah, ya, eso será para, al momento de corregir, supongo, saber a quién pertenece cada código.